# Copying columns into from worksheet into separate Excel files with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Sorry I am new to openpyxl and pandas and I am looking to take the columns of one excel sheet and create separate workbooks containing the first column and one column from the sheet.

```
| Column A | Column B |Column C |
| -------- | -------- |-------- |
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   | Cell 5  |
| Cell 3   | Cell 4   | Cell 6  |
```

I would like the output of each table to be column a followed by one of the other columns.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMgzu.png)

This prints all of the columns out to separate files but no matter where the save function is placed it will always just copy the whole sheet.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

    wb = load_workbook('billingTest.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    column_a = ws['A']
    #row_1 = ws['1']
    row = ws['1']
    counter = 0
    for col in ws.iter_cols():
        counter+=1

        for a in column_a:
            print(a.value)
        
        for cell in col:
            print(cell.value)
        wb.save('billingTest'+str(counter)+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Your code is printing out (to screen) ColA then each of the Columns A-E, AND each time  saves the original opened workbook 'billingTest.xlsx' (as is) with a new file name that includes the variable 'counter' number. So all the saved workbooks will be the same as the original Excel file. It looks as though you want to take ColA and ColB and write to a new file, then ColA and ColC and write to a different new file etc. Therefore you must create and write your column data to a new file since 'billingTest.xlsx' will always have all the columns (unless you delete some which could be another option)

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption of your requirement is correct, the usual way is to copy the required columns to a new excel file and save. There are many questions/answers on how to do this on SO just need to search.

This is an example uses the different angle of deleting the unwanted columns so that only the two columns you require remain then saving the workbook.
The code loads 'billingTest.xlsx' as a binary file then loads the openpyxl workbook from this data using a loop from Column B to the maximum number of columns. Each loop deletes the unwanted columns from the sheet leaving Column A and the next current required. It then saves the numbered workbook.
The workbook needs to be reloaded each time since the columns deleted on the previous loop will be missing on the next loop. Rather than loading the workbook from the file each time its refreshed from the initial file load.
I'm guessing from your example image that B10, C10, D10 and E10 are formulas       summing the columns so the other requirement is to update these formulas as openpyxl does not manage formulas when columns/rows are deleted.
This method can be good for retaining formatting since it is basically saving the original file each time minus the unwanted columns.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from io import BytesIO

file = 'billingTest.xlsx'

with open(file, "rb") as fh:
    wb_data = BytesIO(fh.read())

max_columns = load_workbook(wb_data).active.max_column

for counter in range(2, max_columns+1):
    wb = load_workbook(wb_data)
    ws = wb.active
    for i in reversed(range(2, max_columns+1)):
        if i != counter:
            ws.delete_cols(idx=i)
    ws.cell(10,2).value = '=SUM(B2:B9)'
    wb.save('billingTest' + str(counter-1) + '.xlsx')
```

The result of this code run is 4 excel files, billingTest1.xlsx - billingTest4.xlsx each containing Column A and then for each file, Column B being column B then C then D the E.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The data in the table has actually had all of the formulas removed so that line is unnecessary, but this functions perfectly. Thank you.